# Brace matcher using JFlex

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, jflex

I'm writing an IntelliJ plugin.

One of the functionalities should be a brace matcher. I already did the plugin tutorial from JetBrains. And I also got the brace matcher working with this regular expression `[^@\*\{\}\(\)\$\.]*` so everything is matched by the lexer except these characters. So that the brace matcher can work.

But now I've got a new problem.

Some code specific parts are splitted. So everytime when there is `{` or `}` the code gets splitted.

This is a big problem for JavaScript because the formatter destroys the code.

My question is: How do I get the brace matcher working and keep the right formatting of JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Your lexer should match the entire text of the file. You should be generating tokens for each of the bracket symbols.